# Black screen and losing video signal when running demanding games

Tags: drivers, video, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

I have recently upgraded my system with an [Asus GeForce GTX 970 4GB STRIX Video Card](http://pcpartpicker.com/part/asus-video-card-strixgtx970dc2oc4gd5)

[My build](http://pcpartpicker.com/p/Y4JRsJ) (+ 16GB memory, 1 SSD, 1 HDD)

Now whenever I run something more demanding the monitor loses the signal and the screen goes black requiring a hard reboot of the system. Though I can still hear the sound. My goto tests are the [Unigine Heaven Benchmark](https://unigine.com/products/benchmarks/heaven/) and the Bioshock Infinite Benchmark with the highest video settings.

Is my GPU broken? I have updated to the latest Nvidia drivers using the GeForce Experience application. I have also updated the BIOS to the latest version and deleted all my old GPU drivers (previously had a AMD Radeon HD 6950) using [Display Driver Uninstaller](http://www.wagnardmobile.com/?q=node/78).

Is it the PSU (Corsair Enthusiast 650W 80+ Certified ATX Power Supply) that can't handle the GPU? If so, what should I get instead?

Comment: Your PSU should be able to supply the required power. Could you edit your question to include *how* you removed the AMD drivers?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Updated

Comment: Does your sound go via the video card (the sound playback device will be have something like "NVIDIA High Definition Audio" in its description)? Does the video always disappear after the same time (say, ten minutes)? Is the video lead securely connected at both ends - maybe it falls out a tiny bit when the items it is connected to get hot.

Comment: No the sound card is integrated on the mobo. The video disappear when running the benchmark 2-10 minutes

Comment: Can  you monitor the GPU Temperature during the tests and log it? , I had similar problem and it was because of excesive heat, not enough ventilation, during GPU highest demand the temprature skyrocketed and fans where not correctly setup.

Comment: Normally a video card would respond to excessive high temperatures (perhaps caused by inadequate ventilation) by slowing down rather than shutting down completely. I would take the card out and put it back again to make sure it is correctly seated, and make sure its power connectors are secure (I think your card may have LED indicators to tell you if not). Test again, then, if it still doesn't work, contact the place you bought the video card from to enquire about an RMA. They may have other suggestions. Asus parts are usually very good quality, but one might have slipped through QA.

Comment: @arana I have only seen the card reach ~65-70°C

Comment: Since you can still hear sound it seems to me that everything MIGHT still be working, it might be that your monitor may not handle the higher resolutions/refresh rates/sync  that your adapter can provide during the benchmarks, I would try doing the tests with another display, before trying anything else, maybe even your TV.

Comment: Here are some solutions that worked for some with your same card, apparently you are not the only  one having this problem, 

1 Set your fans to 100% speed.
2 rollback drivers to previous versions.
3 limit the card power to about 60% (performance affected)
 https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/911815/geforce-900-series/gtx-970-strix-black-screen-no-signal-issue/

Comment: @arana Same problem with another monitor (Apple Cinema Display 27")

Comment: run a directx9 benchmark and report back. we dont know if it's heat or driver bug